# Puppeteer & timecut errors with data attribute or normal id selectors when screen record as a video html element content from server or local files

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, screen-recording

From a Node.js script with [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) and [timecut](https://github.com/tungs/timecut) libraries i'm trying to screen record as a video the content of a specific html element based on CSS selector from a web page headless mode. Page is hosted on server or loaded locally from filesystem from the same folder as the script.
Still, i'm unable to do that, because i receive different errors:

1. Error when trying to use an data attribute selector like `selector: '[data-lpid="posterContainer"]'` error is: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')`
2. Also, when trying to use an id selector like `selector: '#some-existing-id '` i get this error: `Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#some-existing-id is not a valid selector.`
3. On same simple pages from local servers with `div` and `video` element inside, i receive `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation`
4. When trying to load local index.html file from the same folder, i tried without path as normal `index.html` or with full path `file:///C:/zFVStuff/cms/poc-cms-video-poster-render-download/basic-puppeteer/test-local-lpac-files/index.html` but i'm receiving: `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded at C:\zFVStuff\DentsuSRC\liveposter\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21`

My code:

```
const timecut = require('timecut');
timecut({
    // url: 'https://tungs.github.io/amuse/truchet-tiles/#autoplay=true&switchStyle=random',
    //  // url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/puppeteer-timecut-element-screen-recorder.html',
    // https://www.pexels.com/video/drone-footage-of-a-surfer-barrelling-a-wave-12715991,
    // url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8ljgrq0YEk',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    viewport: {
        width: 1920,               // sets the viewport (window size) to 800x600
        height: 1080
    },
    // selector: '#container',     // crops each frame to the bounding box of '#container'
    selector: '[data-lpid="posterContainer"]',     // crops each frame to the bounding box of '#container'
    // selector: '#some-existing-id',     
    // selector: '#player-theater-container', // for youtube.com    
    // selector: '#player',     // for pexels.com
    left: 20, top: 40,          // further crops the left by 20px, and the top by 40px
    right: 6, bottom: 30,       // and the right by 6px, and the bottom by 30px
    fps: 30,                    // saves 30 frames for each virtual second
    // duration: 20,               // for 20 virtual seconds 
    duration: 10,               // for 20 virtual seconds 
    output: 'video-timecut.mp4',         // to video.mp4 of the current working directory
    // headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
}).then(function () {
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

Example of html code that i want to record:

```
// html... head... body... (removed for brevity)...

<div id="some-existing-id" data-lpid="posterContainer">
    <video crossorigin="" src="/some-video.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="" muted
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></video>
    <div class="css-animated-text">
        some CSS animated text
    </div>
</div>

// ... removed for brevity
```

Detailed errors:

```
Page loaded
Capturing Frame 1 to C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\timecut-temp-1661987464345\image-000000001.png...
Capturing Frame 2 to C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\timecut-temp-1661987464345\image-000000002.png...
Capturing Frame 3 to C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\timecut-temp-1661987464345\image-000000003.png...
Capturing Frame 4 to C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\timecut-temp-1661987464345\image-000000004.png...
Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
    at rewriteError (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:167:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:120:56)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:48:12)
    at async runInAllFrames (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\lib\utils.js:49:7)
    at async run (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:253:9)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:287:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:210:7)
```

```
Page loaded
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:18
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:48:12)
    at async Object.beforeCapture (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\lib\capture-screenshot.js:45:22)
    at async run (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:277:9)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:287:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:210:7)
```

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58924/devtools/browser/026aedc3-de58-47d6-b2f7-283c6c427d05
Capture Mode: Screenshot
Going to file://C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\test-local-lpac-files\index.html...
[0901/193102.224:INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "[object Object] [object Object]", source: file:///C:/zFVStuff/DentsuSRC/liveposter/cms/poc-cms-video-poster-render-download/basic-puppeteer/test-local-lpac-files/bundle.js (45)
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:672:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at run (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:175:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:287:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:210:7)
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
    at C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:672:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at run (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:175:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timesnap\index.js:287:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:210:7)
node:fs:1390
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
0107'
    at deleteFolder (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:54:6)
    at module.exports (C:\zFVStuff\cms\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\basic-puppeteer\node_modules\timecut\index.js:244:5) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\zFVStuff\\cms\\poc-cms-video-poster-render-download\\basic-puppeteer\\test-local-lpac-files\\recorded-videos\\timecut-temp-1662049860107'
}
```

Stack:

- OS: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04
- Node Version v16.13.0
- Timecut Version v0.3.3
- Puppeteer Version v16.2.0
- Chrome Version V105 (for Windows 10)

Also opened [a bug](https://github.com/tungs/timecut/issues/67) on the timecut github repo.

Great job with the library! Thank you very much in advance for any help!